# Execute a statement right after VC++ window has been set up

Tags: visual-c++, user-interface, constructor, window, execute

I have a function that relies on GUI elements of the window. I want to execute this function right after the window has been set up with all its elements. If I call this function in the constructor, however, the program crashes, most certainly because it relies on the GUI elements that are not initalized yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not call the function until your GUI is setup properly=)

Comment: But I do want to call it automatically, if not I wouldn't have asked this question. And I don't want to use an ugly delay of some secs or sth like that...

Comment: I also tried a loop that checks if some GUI elements equal NULL and only executes the function if not, but checking that causes a crash as well.

Comment: Use the WM_CREATE message that Windows sends.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to overload the OnInitDialog() and call the function and the CDialog::OnInitDialog() from there if you used the DDX functions to initialize your dialog members.